# Within a container control, How to scroll to a out-of-view target WINFORM control

Tags: .net, winforms

Within a container control, say a PictureBox with vertical scroll bars turned on, how does one determine if a control is visible and, if not, scroll to it so that it is visible?

Comment: unable to understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your purpose is just to scroll in order to make a control visible within a container (that must inherit from `ScrollableControl`), you can use:

```
container.ScrollControlIntoView(childControl);
```

Answer (score 0):

can you set the child control's position to left = 0, top = 0?

Comment: Maybe this sample scenario will explain why not: if you have a questionnaire form with 10 yestions on it, vertically spanning the space of the container control and there is an error on question #10, are you suggestion that I move question 1 to the top and shuffle the order of the questions or wouldnt it be better to just scroll the container to the end of the list to see question 10?